# Rake tasks in separate gems conflicting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake-task

I am building two separate gems, using Railties to bring in rake tasks from each gem. The tasks are in different namespaces, and when I bring in each separately in a Gemfile, the task shows up in rake -T, but when both gems are in the same Gemfile, only the second gem's task shows up. It's as if the second gem's task stomps the first, despite namespacing.

```
class AfsTest::Railtie < Rails::Railtie
  railtie_name :afs_test

  rake_tasks do
    load 'tasks/config.rake'
  end
end

namespace :afs do
  namespace :test do
    desc 'Configure afs_test gems'
    task :config do
      puts 'placeholder'
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class AfsDevTest::Railtie < Rails::Railtie
  railtie_name :afs_dev_test

  rake_tasks do
    load 'tasks/config.rake'
  end
end

namespace :afs do
  namespace :dev_test do
    desc 'Configure afs_dev_test gems'
    task :config do
      Rails::Generators.invoke('rspec:install')
    end
  end
end
```

(Yes, I know the gems don't do much - that's not the point here. The point is that one stomps the other.)

Comment: Can you print `$:`? I would try to change `load 'tasks/config.rake'` to `load 'tasks/afs_test.rake'` and `load 'tasks/afs_dev_test.rake'`

Comment: I'll give that a shot.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what fixed it, but I also put it in the development, test groups instead of just test. The strange part is that the test gem was in just the test group, so I don't know why its rake tasks were showing up *at all*.

But it works now, thanks!